# C# - Partial Class in the VS2005 project

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2005

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Visual Studio (2008) is there a way to have a custom dependent file on another custom file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727898/in-visual-studio-2008-is-there-a-way-to-have-a-custom-dependent-file-on-another)

How can I add a partial class in a VS2005 project so that it shows up as a code behind file for the main file?

For example: I want to keep my class-properties in a file named, `MyClass.cs` and I want to keep my class-attributes in a file named `MyClass.attr.cs`.

When I open the VS2005 project, the `MyClass.attr.cs`-file would show up as a code behind file for `MyClass.cs`, just like `Form1.cs` and `Form1.Designer.cs` in a winform application.

Comment: You can do this in the project file - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/727898

Comment: WTF in closing a thread? Is this VS2005? These people don't know the difference between VS2005 and VS2008. Strange!

Answer (score 2):

In your .csproj file you'll see seperate tags for the classes, like this:

```
<Compile Include="MyClass.attr.cs" />
<Compile Include="MyClass.cs" />
```

Change the entry for *MyClass.attr.cs* to be like this:

```
<Compile Include="MyClass.attr.cs">
  <DependentUpon>MyClass.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is not posible set in UI of visual Studio, but if you open *.csproj in notepad, you will see, the "Form1.designer.cs" is assigned as "subitem" of "Form1.cs".

Maybe there is way, how to do it with macors in Visual Studio.