# How to add generated code files in VS 2010 as dependent files?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, code-generation, t4

I am automating my project using T4 templates. For this, I have to write some repeated code using T4 template and some hand written code which should not be overwritten by the T4 template. I would like to add the generated code file as the dependent file of the handwritten file. I am following convention of class1.cs for handwritten file and class1.generated.cs for generated file. How can I add this generated file in the project as dependent file of class1.cs?

Answer (score 1):

To do this programmatically you'll have to modify the .csproj file directly. Refer to this question for details:
[In Visual Studio (2008) is there a way to have a custom dependent file on another custom file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727898/in-visual-studio-2008-is-there-a-way-to-have-a-custom-dependent-file-on-another)

If you want to do this via the IDE then use the VSCommonds Add-in for Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Thanks Ben. But I wanted to do it in VS 2010. The VSCommands Lite add-in is able to do it through their group files command.

Comment: Sorry I thought you wanted to do this programmatically (because you were generating code). Agreed that VSCommands add-in is the way to go (that's what we use). Updated my answer accordingly.