# How to combine App.config files to have expandable folder like structure

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

In an existing C# WPF solution I can see the app.config and app.release.config files are combined in a folder like structure:

[image: Desired config structure]

However in my new solution I cannot duplicate this functionality and get this instead:

[image: Current state]

This is clearly less appealing and takes up a lot of space in the solution explorer. **How can I combine my config files to have a folder-like structure?**

*note: 
I posted this Q/A because I was unable to find anything regarding this issue until I already had the solution and knew exactly what to search for.. After that I found a few similar questions like this one: [In Visual Studio (2008) is there a way to have a custom dependent file on another custom file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727898/in-visual-studio-2008-is-there-a-way-to-have-a-custom-dependent-file-on-anothe). Hopefully this helps someone else find the answer quicker than I did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After lots of file comparisons I found the key in the project file (`ProjectName.csproj`). To achieve the desired structure you have to make the child configs dependant on the original. Similar to how views have dependant code files.

Change:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="App.config">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </None>
    <None Include="App.Production.config" />
    <None Include="App.DR.config" />
    <None Include="App.INTLiberty.config" />
    <None Include="App.Release.config" />
    <None Include="App.UAT.config" />
    <None Include="App.Training.config" />
    <None Include="App.QAProd.config" />
    <None Include="App.INTOvation.config" />
    <None Include="App.QA.config" />
    <None Include="App.QAEnv3.config" />
    <None Include="App.QAEnv2.config" />
    <None Include="App.QAEnv1.config" />
    <None Include="App.Development.config" />
    <None Include="App.Debug.config" />
</ItemGroup>
```

To:

```
<ItemGroup>        
    <None Include="App.Production.config" >
        <DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>
    </None>
    <None Include="App.DR.config" >
        <DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>
    </None>
    <None Include="App.INTLiberty.config" >
        <DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>
    </None>
    <None Include="App.Release.config" >
        <DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>
    </None>
    <None Include="App.UAT.config" >
        <DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>
    </None>
    <None Include="App.Training.config" >
        <DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>
    </None>
    <None Include="App.QAProd.config" >
        <DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>
    </None>
    <None Include="App.INTOvation.config" >
        <DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>
    </None>
    <None Include="App.QA.config" >
        <DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>
    </None>
    <None Include="App.QAEnv3.config" >
        <DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>
    </None>
    <None Include="App.QAEnv2.config" >
        <DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>
    </None>
    <None Include="App.QAEnv1.config" >
        <DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>
    </None>
    <None Include="App.Development.config" >
        <DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>
    </None>
    <None Include="App.Debug.config" >
        <DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>
    </None>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="App.config" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the easiest solution (editing project file) by RyanS to solve this problem. Sometime back I went through similar situation and solved like this. Hope this helps someone.

1) We can easily add transformation configs to web.config just by clicking "Add Config Transform" menu item.

[image]

This will add only number of solution configurations available. If you want to add more transformation configs then you need to add new configurations first. In this below case it will create only two transformations (Debug & Release)

[image]

2) Coming to App.config, one will not see this "Add Transform" menu item. Install [SlowCheetah](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) plugin and that will add this menu item and then follow step 1.

Comment: The `Configuration Transform` plugin works nicely as well, and is a bit cleaner IMHO.

Comment: @code4life I like that...https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/579d3a78-3bdd-497c-bc21-aa6e6abbc859